# Best way to do "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

What is the best way to do "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in Spring Data JPA? Right now I'm doing that using native query (using "Query" and "Modifying" annotation). But the problem with that is that it doesn't trigger Hibernate lifecycle. So I'm not able to audit the table entries using Hibernate envers, nor does "PrePersist" is getting called for my entity (I want some fields to be pre-filled, which I'm doing using PrePersist). Is there any other method to do "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in Spring Data JPA which triggers the above events, or can I trigger those events using native query only somehow?

Comment: Are you asking about merge operation?

Comment: @Abhijeet yes talking about merge operation

Comment: Anyone came across a solution to this?