# how to SELECT FOR UPDATE against a Unique Constraint such that does not cause a deadlock

Tags: transactions, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to do an `UPSERT` type operation, but I am trying to do it with simple SQL that can work with JPA so the solution in

[How to Perform an UPSERT so that I can use both new and old values in update part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par) does not work for me.

In DBeaver, I set up two windows against AWS Aurora Serverless database and set it to have **Manual Commit (Serializable)** (FWIW I also tried **Repeatable Read**)

Here's my sequence

```
-- window A
select * from alert a where a.server_id ='x' and a.alert_id = 1 for update;

-- window B
select * from alert a where a.server_id ='x' and a.alert_id = 1 for update;
```

My expectation is that the second window will pause but instead it actually performed the query.  Instead the following happened.

```
-- window A
insert into alert (id, server_id, alert_id, data, ...) 
  values (123, 'x', 1, '{...}', ...);
```

The window freezes because of the lock on window B.  Then doing this

```
-- window B
insert into alert (id, server_id, alert_id, data, ...) 
  values (123, 'x', 1, '{...}', ...);
```

Raises a deadlock

Now what I want is to prevent the deadlock by making the `select * from alert a where a.server_id ='x' and a.alert_id = 1 for update;` block any operations that involve that select statement.  The reason is if I have a row, I would do an `update` operation rather than `insert`.

I guess I can use `LOCK TABLE` but that's kind of overkill and not part of the JPA spec.

I've also tested on a local MySQL server not Aurora and still the same issue.

Just to make sure, I also tried it with the CLI and same result

[image]

I think the problem from what I understand on the [`select` reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

> If you use FOR UPDATE with a storage engine that uses page or row locks, rows examined by the query are **write-locked** until the end of the current transaction.

But I need it **read-locked** as well somehow.

Comment: A way to make both transactions avoid deadlocking is to change the isolation level to READ COMMITTED which should prevent a transaction waiting indefinitely for the other. 
i.e. Run `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;` before starting the transaction

Comment: If I do that and I insert with the same values won't that cause a unique constraint error then?

Comment: if there is a unique constraint violation caused by those commands - isn't that what you want if there is a unique constraint? the question is how to avoid the deadlock

Comment: The thing is I want it to block on the select rather than after, if it did that then the second select will give a result once the first transaction has finished.  Because it does not it creates a deadlock situation.

Comment: 1) amazon aurora is not mysql, just highly compatible with mysql (and postgresql). 2) if it supports mysql's locking function (get_lock() and its companions) then those might be better suited for your needs as those implement the mutex pattern. 3) in mysql I would not use the locking read at all. I would have a unique undex on the server and alert fields and woukd try to insert a row. If the insertion succeeds, then the transaction has the lock. If it fails with duplicate key error, then you know it has to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Going by this post

[How do I lock on an InnoDB row that doesn't exist yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068686/how-do-i-lock-on-an-innodb-row-that-doesnt-exist-yet)

this is exactly what I sort of needed.  Though the selected answer is incorrect.

The gist is MySQL does not support locks on non-existent rows.  What I need to do is implement a mutex table as a workaround.  So the sequence would be

```sql
SELECT * FROM MUTEX WHERE NAME='myTable' FOR UPDATE;
...
```

then do rest of my operations where select mutex will prevent further movement.

The `MUTEX` table would be (being restrictive on size and characters)

```sql
CREATE TABLE MUTEX (
    name VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin PRIMARY KEY,
    acquired BOOLEAN
);
```

Because I would need the seed table I have to rely on a **native query** which can be written out as follows

```java
@Modifying
@Query(native = """
  INSERT INTO MUTEX (name, acquired) VALUES (:mutexName, true)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE acquired = false
  """)
Integer createMutex(String mutexName);

@Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) // so it will do for update
Optional<Mutex> findByName(String name);

default Mutex acquireMutex(String name) {
  return findByName(name).orElseThrow(()->new MutexIsNotDefinedception(name));
}
```

on the Mutex table.  The good part is it is isolated and it can be designed to not need any lifecycle events as noted in the question:
[Best way to do "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" using Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868080/best-way-to-do-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-using-spring-data-jpa)

After which the `upsert` operations can be performed using a simple

```
mutexesRepo.acquireMutex("myMutex");
var entity = repo.findByFooAndBar(foo, bar)
  .orElse(new MyEntity(foo, bar));
myEntitiesRepo.save(entity);
```

No extra `@Lock` annotations would be needed at that point because everything can be managed by a single mutex lock now.

I guess that's why both Liquibase and Shedlock had similar patterns.

---

However, there's going to be a performance problem with the above, in that there's a single mutex which means if you do frequent upserts this won't make much sense.  You can implement native queries to do it throughout but you lose Spring Data JPA's simple `save` functionality.  You also need to handle the case of the generated primary key which is no available when you do a native insert query.

You can add more logic to the mutex key so that instead of a straight forward string, we can use a SHA256 hash of the input fields. It would mean a lot of useless rows though but it does not need to take in the full SHA256 bytes so you can tune appropriately.  Going by that idea

The `MUTEX` table would be written as the following assuming I am only keeping the first byte of the SHA256 computation or some other hashing algortithm.

```
CREATE TABLE MUTEX (
    name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin,
    datahash BINARY(1),
    acquired BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, datahash)
);
```

So the create method would be defined as

```java
@Modifying
@Query(native = """
  INSERT INTO MUTEX (name, dataHash, acquired) VALUES (:mutexName, :dataHash, true)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE acquired = false
  """)
Integer createMutex(String mutexName, byte[] dataHash);

default Integer createMutexes(String mutexName) {
  int length = 1; // Change this to the desired byte array length
  Stream<byte[]> allPossibleValues = 
    generateAllByteArrayPermutations(length);
  allPossibleValues.forEach(a->
    createMutex(name, a));
}

@Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) // so it will do for update
Optional<Mutex> findByNameAndDataHash(String name, byte[] dataHash);

default acquireMutex(String name, Serializable... data) {
  var dataHash = computeDataHash(data);
  findByName(name, dataHash).orElseThrow(()->new MutexIsNotDefinedception(name, dataHash));
}
```

(MOD feel free to delete this question, but it is a scenario specific enough that keeping it will help find the solution)